# git: Have files inside the repo, so they get pulled when cloned, but ignored otherwise?

Tags: git

Is it possible to have files inside the repo so they get cloned. But they should not be pushed?

We have some config files which are needed for our code. But they need changes for every machine.

Comment: do you use `.gitignore`?

Comment: The usual approach is to check in template files (let's say `myLocalConfig-template.conf`) and put the actually used file names into `.gitignore` (let's say that's `myLocalConfig.conf`). Then you can either require each developer to copy the template to the actual file manually or automate that via your build tool or even git hooks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+application+config

Comment: @phd git update-index --skip-worktree seems to be exactly what I need, thx. Just one more question: This is only locally, right? So every developer has to do that once when setting up their dev machine?

Comment: "*This is only locally, right? So every developer has to do that once*" Yes.

Comment: @phd And you only have to do it once? Or every time you branch?